# interface conversion: interface {} is uint64, not float32

Tags: go

Basically I have `map[interface{}]interface{}`  and inside under key "x" value 90 (I printed to confirm that data are correct), but when I do

```
mymap["x"].(float32)
```

I get error

```
interface conversion: interface {} is uint64, not float32
```

Problem is that I expect float number (produced from as output from another program). I also tried to float32(mymap["x"]) but not success(also tried examples from google with int64 without success).

I am using **go version go1.10.1 linux/amd64**

Comment: You may use conversion after the type assertion: `float32(mymap["x"].(uint64))` https://play.golang.org/p/fBGUf4EDOMD

Comment: @mkopriva But this is a question I am receiving sometimes there 45.5 for example a when is round 45 and not 45.0. I can resolve this with reflection and explicit conversion but I wanted to avoid that step if is possible, to avoid reflection as slower part to be called additionally.

Comment: Would a type switch solve your problem? https://play.golang.org/p/Xe2qt634-D5

Comment: You probably should solve this problem at the level where you are populating the map. But you didn't mention _how_ you are doing that.

Comment: What Michael said. Try not to use an empty interface if you care about types.

Answer (score 0):

this is my script:

```
switch i := x.(type) {
case nil:
    printString("x is nil")                // type of i is type of x (interface{})
case int:
    printInt(i)                            // type of i is int
case float64:
    printFloat64(i)                        // type of i is float64
case func(int) float64:
    printFunction(i)                       // type of i is func(int) float64
case bool, string:
    printString("type is bool or string")  // type of i is type of x (interface{})
default:
    printString("don't know the type")     // type of i is type of x (interface{})
}
```